# Spring Mongo Criteria Complex Query Matching inner object field of Querying entity

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I have two Entities

```
   class EntityA{
        @Id
        String id;
        ..... other class fields 
        ..... getter/setters
    }

   class EntityB{
   @Id
   String id;
   Integer age;
   EntityA entityA;
        ..... other class fields 
        ..... getter/setters
   }
```

and I am querying **EntityB** by matching the `id of entityA` objects.

Here is what I'm trying to do

```
    Criteria criteria = Criteria.where("age").gte(0).lt(100);

    EntityA entityA = new EntityA();
    entityA.setId("theIdIHave");
    Example<EntityA> eaEx = Example.of(entityA);
    criteria = criteria.andOperator(Criteria.byExample(eaEx));

    Query query = new Query();
    query.addCriteria(criteria);

    List<EntityB> res = mongoTemplate.find(query,EntityB.class);
```

But it throws

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: json can't serialize type : class org.springframework.data.domain.Example
```

two things 
Is my approach of using org.springframework.data.domain.Example is correct ??
and why is error

Comment: Please provide sample document

Comment: You don't have to use `Example` class, just use Criteria is fine. Don't wrap it.

Answer (score 0):

Try below. It will deserialize the result and map into EntityB `pojo` class

```
Query query = new Query();
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("age").gte(0).lt(100).and("entityA.id").is("theIdIHave");
List<EntityB> res = mongoTemplate.find(query, EntityB.class);
```